# Using AJAX function inside of ajaxComplete function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page that is being populated by parsing information from a CSV file and then display it in list form. Once the list is populated, I am using the jQuery UI accordion to make it an accordion menu. My code looks like this:

```
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
        $('div#accordion > ul').accordion({collapsible: true, active:false});
    });
```

I have to wait until the ajax is complete or else there won't be any data to make into an accordion menu. I am then needed to apply click actions to these list items. When I click on the list item, it does an AJAX call and pulls in more data from that CSV. So I'm essentially called an AJAX request within an ajaxComplete function.I can't use `$(window).load();` here because the initial AJAX function is called asynchronously so that wouldn't work.

The issue is that when I run use the click function it works and then the second I use it it runs twice and the third time it runs 4 times, etc. I'm assuming this is because is running the ajax function and then running the ajaxcomplete function which contains the ajax function and it keeps multiplying.

I was trying to think of setting a 'hasRun' variable to true and false but couldn't figure out how to incorporate it into the loop to stop it from running more than once.

Any ideas? Thanks for your help!

Comment: `ajaxComplete` is global.. if that code should only be run after one ajax call in particular, why not put it in the completed callback of that one ajax call?

Comment: Ah good idea, let me look into that. I don't know why I was doing it that way.

Comment: Hi @JasonP, perfect. Thank you! You can write it as an answer if you'd like and I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ajaxComplete` is global.. if that code should only be run after one ajax call in particular, you can just put it in the completed callback of that one ajax call.